# C# Blazor specify string parameter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

My question is pretty simple: how can I specify a parameter inside my URL, for example, if the URL is

`https://localhost:5001/passParameter/thisIsAString`

and I have the code

```
@code {
    <p>@(urlParameter)</p>

    [Parameter] public string urlParameter { get; set; }
}
```

then the page will say "thisIsAString"? I searched everywhere but found no solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the route parameter in the `@page` directive and it will be assigned to the property in the component of the same name:

```
@page "/passParameter/{urlParameter}"

<p>@(urlParameter)</p>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string urlParameter { get; set; }
}
```

See [Route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters-1) for more details.